# Which has higher resolution? GPS or accelerometer?

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer

I have two separate applications. With the accelerometer, the X, Y, and Z axes, as well as orientation, have constatly changing records, meaning that the accelerometer is more dynamic. The GPS, on the other hand, changes when I've significantly moved from my home to a different location. Is higher resolution based on how many times the values change, accuracy, or my movement before there's any recognized change?

Comment: Accelerometer is based on the movement of your phone, hence it will always update values even with minor movement. But gps is based on the location signals available to the device. In general both are independent. And accuracy of one has nothing to do with accuracy of another. But since you have asked this question I feel you have something else in your mind. Can you post what exactly you are trying to implement in your app so that viewers cam suggest precise solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare these both sensors, they have nothing in common.

Think yourself, what you understand under resolution.

The **frequency** of sensor data output is higher at the accelerometer,
from GPS it is 1 per second (1hz). accelerometer has much higher data delivery frequency.

GPS is used to measure absolute locations.
You cannot use the accelerometer to calculate absoulte location.
Even relative movement is unusable after a few seconds (see Google Research Video on Sensor Fusioning).
But an accelerometer can well be used to detect whether a device stands still or it moves slowly.

GPS has an effective accuracy of about 2-3m,
while acceleromter is measured in g. (Gravity force)

To your text:

> "The GPS, on the other hand, changes when I've significantly moved
>   from my home to a different location."

No, GPS delivers exactly each second a location, whether or not you move. APIs like in ios or in Android might supress the delivery when the vehicle obiously does not move. But this is post processing. Some GPS chips can also be configured to supress location updates when the device probably stands still. This can either be speed dependent (e.g <5km/h) or accelerometer dependent for very new GPS chips.
Delievries of significant location movement is usually not done by GPS chip, it is GSM cell tower lcoationing when you move more than 1000m).